# Copy a remote directory using Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I want to copy a directory from a remote server to my client using chef recipe. The 'remote_file' resource can be used to copy a file. remote_directory can copy a directory locally in cookbook files. I cannot find a way to copy a remote directory recurcive. I want to do something like following :

```
remote_file/direcotry 'Copying the folder' do
        path 'c:/repo/OpenOffice4.1.0'
        source 'file:////10.132.17.53/e$/CHEFREPO/OpenOffice 4.1.0 (en-US) Installation Files'
end
```

Comment: I think you're able to zip the orignal dir and the use [remote_install](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/remote_install) or [ark](https://github.com/burtlo/ark) to get and unzip it. You'll save time and bandwith too. If not I've a workaround with mount and execute resources.

Comment: @Tensibai Oops didn't see your comment. Great minds on the use of "ark" :-)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor No problem ;) Your answer is far clearest than my comment

Answer (score 1):

The [remote_file](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_remote_file.html) resource supports the HTTP and FTP protocols. While it's feasible to iterate thru the files contained in a remote directory it's not trivial.

Another consideration is security. The [remote_file](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_remote_file.html) resource allows a checksum to be specified for the remote file so that chef is able to determine the correct file is downloaded.

So.. Hopefully this goes some way to explain why a remote directory resource is not available by default in chef.

But.. Hope is not lost. Here are some suggestions (lots of other ways to replicate a file system I'm sure);

### Download and expand a tarball

Package the remote directory as a compressed tar package

```
tar cf mydir-0.1.tar /data/mydir
gzip mydir.tar
```

The [ark cookbook](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/ark) is my favourite way to manage archives

```
ark 'mydir' do
  url 'http://host/filesystems/mydir-0.1.tar.gz'
  version '0.1'
  checksum 'XXXXXXX'
  path '/data'
end
```

I also like the fact that the expanded tarball is versioned. Think of this as a poor man's snapshotting :-)

### rsync

There us an [rsync cookbook](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/rsync) available that allows an rsync server to be setup on the remote machine.

It's also possible to run rsync over ssh but this will require the setup of SSH keys in advance.

This is the problem with all sync solutions how to setup authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in .rb file:

```
remote_file 'path where remote file will be downloaded' do
            source "remote_file url"
            action :create
end
```

we can specify path using **path** property of remote_file as well.

```
            path "path where remote file will be downloaded"
```